# Vue.js dynamic values for component properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue.js I'm trying to pass values from a loop as properties for a custom component.

```
<template v-for="upload in uploads">
   <upload-container index="{{ $index }}" filename="{{ upload.name }}"></upload-container>
 </template>
```

Unfortunately this does not work and it only passes through the literal strings `{{ $index }}` and `{{ upload.name }}` instead of the actual values.

Answer (score 2):

The values are in fact, passed down as strings. If you want to evaluate the expressions you need to use dynamic syntax.

```
<template v-for="upload in uploads">
   <upload-container :index="$index" :filename="upload.name"></upload-container>
 </template>
```

[Literal vs Dynamic](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Literal_vs-_Dynamic)